# Problem adding operator condition to the string

Tags: php

I need to add `AND` or `OR` in-between my Query string. My conditions are as follows:

### first case:

```
$array = [
    "month" => "October",
    "year"  => 2020,
    "information  => "October 2020"
];
```

In this case, i need

`"(MONTH(b.day) = 'October' AND YEAR(b.day) = '2020') OR b.information LIKE '%October 2020%'"`

second case:

```
$array = [
    "month" => "October",
    "information  => "October 2020"
];
```

In this case, i need

`"(MONTH(b.day) = 'October') OR b.information LIKE '%October 2020%'"`

I have tried following lines of code but I couldn't fix the AND OR in correctly.

```
    $whereStr = '';
    $alias = "b.";
    $orCounter = 0;
    $andCounter = 0;
    $dateMonth = false;

    if (array_key_exists('year', $array) && array_key_exists('month', $array)) {
        $dateMonth = true;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (0 !== $orCounter) {
            $whereStr .= ' OR ';
        } elseif ($andCounter > 0 && true === $dateMonth) {
            $whereStr .= ' AND ';
        }

        if ('month' === $key || 'year' === $key) {
            ++$andCounter;
            echo $andCounter;
            $whereStr .= strtoupper($key) . '(' . $alias . 'day' . ')';
            $whereStr .= "= '$value'";

            if ($andCounter === 2) {
                ++$orCounter;
            }

            continue;
        }

        if ('type' === $key) {
            $whereStr .= "$alias$key IN ($value)";
            continue;
        }
        $whereStr .= "$alias$key LIKE '%$value%'";
        ++$orCounter;
    }
```

Can anybody please help me fix this?

Comment: `information` key is always present?

Comment: Yes it is present

Comment: If you have pasted your code correctly then you are building your array incorrectly especially the 'information' element.

Comment: is this the extent of your criteria? you could just simply use a step down approach, no need for loop actually. and if `information` is always an `OR` condition, just simply append it on the end. and be careful though, you prolly need to use placeholders instead of directly injecting the values inside the query.

Answer (score 1):

just use simple if else conditions why using loop

```
$where ='';
if(isset($array['month']) &&  isset($array['year']) &&  isset($array['information'])){
 $where  = '(MONTH(b.day) = '".$array['month']."' and YEAR(b.day) = '".$array['year']."' ) or b.information like "%'.$array['information'].'%" ';
}else if(isset($array['month']) &&  !isset($array['year']) &&  isset($array['information']))
{
 $where  = '(MONTH(b.day) = '".$array['month']."' ) or b.information like "%'.$array['information'].'%" ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's cleaner with arrays:

```
$AND[] = "`fieldA` = 'Bar'";
$AND[] = "`fieldB` = 'Foo'";
$andString = implode(' AND ',$AND);
```

$andString is

```
`fieldA` = 'Bar' AND `fieldB` = 'Foo'
```

So your code can be

```
$qq = "SELECT * from foobar WHERE $andString";
```